# sub report starting in new page and adding extra page at end in PDF using jasper reports

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I am having a main report with three report groups. each report group header is having a sub report. when i generate the PDF file using the jasper report

1. Its adding some blank space between the sub reports i.e., if the first sub report occupies more than 60% of the first page automatically the second sub report is starting in the new page.
   I cant use ispageignoration because we will generate the pdf for
   multiple records where each record should start in new page.
2. Its generating a blank page at the end just with the page header

the text fields(value1, value2... value6) in second report may have max of 2000characters..

can any one please help me..

Main Report report1.jrxml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
        <parameter name="logoStream" class="java.awt.Image" isForPrompting="false"/>
        <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Other  Drive\\eHRM\\17365\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="dataSource1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
        <field name="dataSource2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
        <field name="dataSource3" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
        <group name="Group1" isStartNewPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="20">
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement x="-30" y="0" width="535" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataSource1}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "/report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <group name="Group2">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="20">
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement x="-30" y="0" width="535" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataSource2}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "/report1_subreport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <group name="group3">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="20">
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement x="-30" y="0" width="535" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataSource3}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "/report1_subreport3.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <pageHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <image>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[(java.awt.Image)$P{logoStream}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="510" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </pageHeader>
    </jasperReport>
```

The Three subreports will be in same format as the below jrxml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
        <field name="title1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="title2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="title3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="title4" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value4" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="title5" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value5" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="title6" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value6" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <detail>
            <band height="161" splitType="Stretch">
                <elementGroup>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="27" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value2} == null || $F{value2}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="33" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </elementGroup>
                <elementGroup>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="54" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value3} == null || $F{value3}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="60" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </elementGroup>
                <elementGroup>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="81" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value4} == null || $F{value4}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="87" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="87" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </elementGroup>
                <elementGroup>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="108" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value5} == null || $F{value5}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="114" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="114" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </elementGroup>
                <elementGroup>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="135" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value6} == null || $F{value6}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="141" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title6}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="141" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value6}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </elementGroup>
                <elementGroup>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="6" width="120" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="120" y="6" width="415" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="535" height="5" forecolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{value1} == null || $F{value1}.equals( "" )) ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    </line>
                </elementGroup>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

A person may have n number of companies so i spited the company name, job profile, project description in to sub report.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Name: XXX
DOB: XX-XX-XXXX
Personal Profile: (** this field may have 2000 characters****)
Skill Sets : (** this also will have 2000 characters**)

Professional Experience:

Company name: XXXX
Job Profile: (** this also will have 2000 characters**)
Project Description :(** this also will have 2000 characters**)

Company name: YYYYY
Job Profile: (** this also will have 2000 characters**)
Project Description :(** this also will have 2000 characters**)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

my  requirement is to generate the PDf similar to it.

Comment: You should post your *jrxml* file. What is your question?

Comment: I have posted my JRXML Files.. can any one please help me with this issue....

Comment: What is your question? What report's design is your goal?

Comment: I have modified the question with the clear requirement.. please help me...